# PhoneGap vs android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm developping now a social network (I can't tell exactly of what) and I want to hear some opinions.Should I use phonegap or use android and iOS?.

Comment: phonegap vs native... native is best ! most social networks gone native too !

Answer (score 3):

I asked the same question when I first started our App, but my answer was easier because I have a "time" restriction which result in us choosing PhoneGap.  Here are some of my reasonings:

Do I really know how to write native app?  No.

Do I know HTML5, css, and javascript?  Bingo.

First, you have to understand that PhoneGap is just a embedded webview/browser inside of the resulting native app.   You still have to use native code to build PhoneGap App, so you can consider learning PhoneGap as step 1 toward learning how to write native app.

PhoneGap has taught me a lot about the native app and project structure on each platform.  I pretty sure it will be easier now for me to write native app than if I were two months ago.

We develop single application for multiple clients.  Part of our agile approach, PhoneGap has allow us to get the application out to the client for review, feedback, and quickly make changes to fit the client need with regards to UI layout and design.  Once the client approve the design; obviously, we can always convert the design to native App if the client is willing to pay for the extra effort.

Comment: Actually I have Knowledge with Android but the Problem is the other os, I mean iOS and windows phone at least

Comment: I couldn't agree more with @Noogen. I'm currently working in a phonegap application and could learn a lot. Today if needed to develop a native app I'm much much more confident and skilled on that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a good app and you are willing to put some time in it, go native.
As a matter of fact, always go native

Comment: It's sounds good, but when I see some advantages of phonegap...somehow i'm confused

Comment: It mostly depends on how deep into the system you want to dive. If you want an app that can handle more than just basic stuff, and you want to make it fast and reliable, it's better to use the native sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you intend to start with something not that complex, I would say go Phonegap.

As you probalby know, the big advantage is that the HTML/JS code you produce is packed into several platforms (Android, iOS, symbian, etc..). However if you need to have more specific services like Background services to interact with the user and so on, you surely will need to develop natively, at least this part.

For example, if you need a service to warn user of updates, etc, you'll have to develop the central application (your html assets) and a background service for Android, and also a bacgrounf service for iOS, it's not possible to reuse code in this case.

So, depend on what you are going to aim at.

Comment: So in this case I must have for each phone os an app (windows phone android ios etc...).It sounds hard but at least I have enough knowledge in Android...But the other is a big question mark